# Is there any way to hide xmlhttprequest log from chrome console

Tags: rest, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, console.log

In my project I'm sending GET request to the server and what I found my every request is displaying in the xmlhttprequest log (attached screenshot) and when you open this with the browser it will show all the data. I'm going to create an API key method for my rest API, While it also takes time, for now, I want to hide logs from the console. So my question is how to hide such types of the log from my chrome console.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view it is not possible to hide any request your are sending with ajax, and another thing is that it is not compulsory to use chrome browser to use, user can use different browser, showing console log is like this is in-build functionality, normal user will not see console log. if your are worried about developers there are many plugin(like firebug) which they can use to monitor  your request/response flow. so if you find any way to hide them it's not 100% solution.

my advice would be you use server side method to call your API if possible.

or second thing you can do is call `console.clear();` function after calling ajax function(possible after success/fail).

Answer (score 0):

you can hide such messages in Chrome in Console > Settings

> (F12 > F1)
>
> Tick   [x] Hide network messages
>
> Untick [] Log XMLHttpRequests

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in the Console Settings > Hide Network
[Hide Network on Console Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXKa8.png)